# java swing remove latest added panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am adding panels to a frame with a button click, each panel goes under the last added panel, I achieve that with `setBounds`, each time incrementing *y* position. There is a second button, that is supposed to remove the latest panel that I added. It should keep removing panels after every click. I have tried a few solutions but they all failed.

My code:

```
public class lab3 {
static int y = 50;
static JButton addThread;
static JPanel results;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setSize(550, 650);
    jFrame.setTitle("Lab3");
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    JPanel panelAddThread = new JPanel();
    panelAddThread.setLayout(null);
    panelAddThread.setBounds(0, 0, 550, 50);
    panelAddThread.setBackground(Color.red);
    JLabel threadLabel = new JLabel();
    threadLabel.setText("Thread count: ");
    addThread = new JButton();
    addThread.setBounds(300, 0, 25, 25);
    addThread.setText("+");
    addThread.setBorder(null);
    addThread.addActionListener(e -> {
        results = new JPanel();
        results.setBounds(0, y, 550, 150);
        results.setBackground(Color.blue);
        results.setLayout(null);
        jFrame.add(results);
        jFrame.repaint();
        y = y+ 150;
    });
    // Remove
    JButton removeThread = new JButton();
    removeThread.setBorder(null);
    removeThread.setBounds(340, 0, 25, 25);
    removeThread.setText("-");
    removeThread.addActionListener(e -> {         
    });
    panelAddThread.add(threadLabel);
    panelAddThread.add(removeThread);
    panelAddThread.add(addThread);
    jFrame.add(panelAddThread);    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Keep a `List` of items as a FIFO queue.  Use a `JList` and make everybodies lives easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are asking for the code for the [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for `removeThread` ([JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)).

`results` is actually the last `JPanel` that you added, so that is the `JPanel` that you need to remove. However, once you remove it, you need to assign it to the new, last `JPanel`, i.e. the second last `JPanel` that was added.

Method [getComponents](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) returns all the components that were added, in the order that they were added. When you remove a component from a `Container` and subsequently call method `getComponents`, the array returned will not contain the component that you just removed. Hence the new, last `JPanel` is the last element in the array returned by method `getComponents`.

All that remains is to handle the "edge" cases.

Here is the code for the `actionPerformed` method:

```java
removeThread.addActionListener(e -> {
    if (results != null) {
        jFrame.remove(results);
        jFrame.repaint();
        y -= 150;
        Container contentPane = jFrame.getContentPane();
        Component[] cmpts = contentPane.getComponents();
        int count = cmpts.length;
        if (count > 1) {
            results = (JPanel) cmpts[count - 1];
        }
        else {
            results = null;
        }
    }
});
```

- If the user clicks `removeThread` **before** clicking `addThread` then `results` will be null.
- If there is only one, added `JPanel` and we remove it, then we need to set `results` to null.

For completeness, here is the entire program, including the above changes.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class lab3 {
    static int y = 50;
    static JButton addThread;
    static JPanel results;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(550, 650);
        jFrame.setTitle("Lab3");
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        JPanel panelAddThread = new JPanel();
        panelAddThread.setLayout(null);
        panelAddThread.setBounds(0, 0, 550, 50);
        panelAddThread.setBackground(Color.red);
        JLabel threadLabel = new JLabel();
        threadLabel.setText("Thread count: ");
        addThread = new JButton();
        addThread.setBounds(300, 0, 25, 25);
        addThread.setText("+");
        addThread.setBorder(null);
        addThread.addActionListener(e -> {
            results = new JPanel();
            results.setBounds(0, y, 550, 150);
            results.setBackground(Color.blue);
            results.setLayout(null);
            jFrame.add(results);
            jFrame.repaint();
            y = y + 150;
        });
        // Remove
        JButton removeThread = new JButton();
        removeThread.setBorder(null);
        removeThread.setBounds(340, 0, 25, 25);
        removeThread.setText("-");
        removeThread.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (results != null) {
                jFrame.remove(results);
                jFrame.repaint();
                y -= 150;
                Container contentPane = jFrame.getContentPane();
                Component[] cmpts = contentPane.getComponents();
                int count = cmpts.length;
                if (count > 1) {
                    results = (JPanel) cmpts[count - 1];
                }
                else {
                    results = null;
                }
            }
        });
        panelAddThread.add(threadLabel);
        panelAddThread.add(removeThread);
        panelAddThread.add(addThread);
        jFrame.add(panelAddThread);
    }
}
```

However, I would write your program differently such that it uses *Swing*'s [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Consider the following:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class LabThree implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel container;
    private JPanel results;

    public void run() {
        buildAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Lab 3");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        buttonsPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        JButton addThreadButton = new JButton("\u2795");
        addThreadButton.addActionListener(this::addThread);
        buttonsPanel.add(addThreadButton);
        JButton removeThreadButton = new JButton("\u2796");
        removeThreadButton.addActionListener(this::removeThread);
        buttonsPanel.add(removeThreadButton);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createMainPanel() {
        container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(container);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(570, 620));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private void addThread(ActionEvent event) {
        results = new JPanel();
        results.setBackground(Color.blue);
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(550, 150);
        results.setMaximumSize(dim);
        results.setMinimumSize(dim);
        results.setPreferredSize(dim);
        container.add(results);
        container.revalidate();
    }

    private void removeThread(ActionEvent event) {
        if (results != null) {
            container.remove(results);
            Component[] cmpts = container.getComponents();
            int count = cmpts.length;
            if (count > 0) {
                results = (JPanel) cmpts[count - 1];
            }
            else {
                results = null;
            }
            container.revalidate();
            container.repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new LabThree());
    }
}
```

- All components added to a [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) are actually added to its *content pane* which, by default, is a `JPanel` whose [default] layout manager is [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).
- Usually you should call method `setVisible` (of class `JFrame`) only **after** you have added all the components.
- After the GUI is displayed and you add or remove components from a container (such as `JPanel`), you need to call method `revalidate`. Sometimes you also need to call method `repaint` after you have called method `revalidate`.
- If you click `addThreadButton` many times, not all the added `JPanel`s will be visible, hence I use [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).
- The text for `addThreadButton` is the Unicode [heavy plus](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9E%95) symbol and the text for `removeThreadButton` is the [heavy minus](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9E%96) symbol.
- The `ActionListener`s are implemented using [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).
- Although not required, it is recommended to explicitly launch the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT), which is done in method `main` in the above code.